# Different values to input fields in Lightning Component

Tags: lightning-aura-components

I have came up with something that challenges me... I want for an iteration of fields to have an input field, but i also need to somehow set and keep a value in order to save them. How could this be done? I mean, to set somehow a unique value for every input field. Code snippet below:

```
<aura:attribute name="questions" type="Question__c[]" />
<aura:iteration items="{!v.questions}" var="item">
    <lightning:input aura:Id="{!item.Id}" type="{!item.Type__c}" name="{!item.name}" label=" 
    {!item.Label__c}" value=??????/>                    
</aura:iteration>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Personally, I'd advise using a "wrapper" to glue everything together.

```
<aura:attribute name="questions" type="Map[]" />

<aura:iteration items="{!v.questions}" var="item">
    <lightning:input aura:id="question" type="{!item.Type__c}" name="{!item.question.Name}" label=" 
    {!item.question.Label__c}" value="{!item.answer.Value__c}" />
</aura:iteration>
```

When you get the return value from loading the questions, just map them using the map function:

```
cmp.set("v.questions", result.getReturnValue().map(record=>({ question: record, answer: { Value__c: '' }})));
```

This is basically the same technique you'd use in Visualforce.

Comment: sfdcfox thank you so much!!!